# object() not a function in redux firebase react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux-firebase, redux-firestore

*TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in reactjs while implementing firebase*
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gf5bVfVlNUM&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9iWstfXntcj8f-dFZ4UtlN3&index=17 
used this tutorial but then error occured 
[ss of browser to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ8df.png)

code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './redux/reducers/rootReducer'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import fbConfig from './config/fbConfig'

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase, getFirestore})),
    reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig),
    reduxFirestore(fbConfig) // redux bindings for firestore
  )
);

store.firebaseAuthIsReady.then(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './redux/reducers/rootReducer'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore, createFirestoreInstance } from 'redux-firestore';
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import fbConfig from './config/fbConfig'
import firebase from "firebase/app";

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase, getFirestore})),
    reduxFirestore(fbConfig) // redux bindings for firestore
  )
);

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config : fbConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
      <App />
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

this one will work fine